# Функции глубины GREATER и GEQUAL в WebGL

Tags: webgl

При задании `gl.deptFunc` GREATER или GEQUAL картинка пропадает, остаётся только фон. Попробовал со стандартным примером (вращающийся кубик из уроков NeHe) -- то же самое. Что надо сделать? Хочу "разобрать на слои".

Comment: У вас фон как рисуется? Какое значение Z он имеет?

Comment: @Kromster gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: А вы очищаете буфер глубины?  `glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )`

Comment: Очищаю, не помогает.

Comment: Хорошо, а какое численное значение имеет очищенный фон, 1 или 0 ? (обычно это максимум - 1) И как идет работа дальше со сравнениями глубины (у вас это все что больше) и какие значения у отрисовываемых объектов (а вот они то обычно меньше 1)? Вот и не рисуются они ;-)

Comment: А как изменить глубину фона?

Comment: Посмотри документацию по функции `glClearDepth`